# Using VBA to set a shape/picture's formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I would like to set the formula for a picture using VBA.

This is a portion of the simplified version of the VBA used to insert and modify a shape/picture from a given URL.

```
    Dim theShape As Shape
    Filename = cell

        ' Use Shapes instead so that we can force it to save with the document
        Set theShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture( _
            Filename:=Filename, linktofile:=msoFalse, _
            savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, _
            Left:=cell.Left, Top:=cell.Top, Width:=60, Height:=60)

        With theShape
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            ' Shape position and sizes stuck to cell shape
            .Top = cell.Top + 1
            .Left = cell.Left + 1
            .Height = cell.Height - 2
            .Width = cell.Width - 2
            ' Move with the cell (and size, though that is likely buggy)
            .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
            .Name = "Item" & cell.Row

            '******What to enter here to set the "Formula" for the picture?
            'Trying to set the formula to an existing named range, such as "FQPic3"
            'Something like: .formula = FQPic3

        End With
```

However, I don't see a picture property to set the formula.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would allow you to set the formula:

```
Dim theShape As Shape
Filename = cell

    ' Use Shapes instead so that we can force it to save with the document
    Set theShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture( _
        Filename:=Filename, linktofile:=msoFalse, _
        savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, _
        Left:=cell.Left, Top:=cell.Top, Width:=60, Height:=60)

    With theShape
        .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        ' Shape position and sizes stuck to cell shape
        .Top = cell.Top + 1
        .Left = cell.Left + 1
        .Height = cell.Height - 2
        .Width = cell.Width - 2
        ' Move with the cell (and size, though that is likely buggy)
        .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
        .Name = "Item" & cell.Row

        '******What to enter here to set the "Formula" for the picture?
        'Trying to set the formula to an existing named range, such as "FQPic3"
        'Something like: .formula = FQPic3
        theShape.OLEFormat.Object.Formula = "=FQPic3"

    End With
```

Side note: didn't check the rest of your code

Comment: This works well.  No need to check the rest of code - the one line is what I was after.  Note for future users: the above code has the dimension properties (height, width) being set before setting the ".Formula".  The formula in my spreadsheet is referring to a Named Range, which INDIRECT refers to another cell - thus the picture displays whatever is in that other cell.  The ".OLEFormat.Object.Formula =" also made the picture take the on dimension properties of the cell being referenced.  So setting the .Formula needs to be done before setting the picture dimension properties (height, width).